# Are there restrictions for emitting in partial trust?

Tags: c#, .net, security, reflection, reflection.emit

The following pages in the MSDN library left me confused:

- [Walkthrough: Emitting Code in Partial Trust Scenarios](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384237(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [DynamicMethod Constructor (String, Type, Type[], Type, Boolean)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc6e708b(v=vs.110).aspx)

MSDN explains that constructing a `DynamicMethod` with `skipVisibility` set to `true` requires the following permissions:

- `ReflectionPermissionFlag.MemberAccess`
- `ReflectionPermissionFlag.RestrictedMemberAccess` (only if the caller is not the owner)

The first page also states the following:

> The restricted ability to skip visibility checks is a feature of anonymously hosted dynamic methods. When ordinary dynamic methods skip JIT visibility checks, they must be granted full trust.

What does "ordinary dynamic methods" mean? I thought all dynamic methods were anonymous. Are there any circumstances where a `DynamicMethod` literally requires full trust instead of those two permissions?

Comment: Yes, that doesn't make sense.  I'd guess it should read "RMA is a feature of dynamic methods created by sandboxed code".